# How to generate 'registrationId' of device for push notification - IONIC

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have installed the cordova and ionic native plugins successfully `ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push` and  `npm install --save @ionic-native/push`

After this i have added below code on my `dashboard.ts` and `app.module.ts`

```
import { Push, PushObject, PushOptions } from '@ionic-native/push';
```

Do i need to add some in `imports` in `app.module.ts` ?

Now i added `private push: Push` in my constructor

Now

```
OnInit(){
// i need to generate a registerationID in a variable which i can see on a popup //to make sure it is generated.
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Write below in your desire method

```
OnInit()
{
  const options: PushOptions = {
     android: {},
     ios: {
         alert: 'true',
         badge: true,
         sound: 'false'
     },
     windows: {},
     browser: {
         pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
     }
  };

  const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);

  pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => console.log('Received a notification', notification));

  pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => console.log('Device registered', registration));

  pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => console.error('Error with Push plugin', error));
}
```

Comment: this is documented, but i am unable to get from which variable will i get the registered ID ?  can you please help me show the registeredID key on a popup so i canmake android apk and check ?

Comment: Write alert(registration) instead of console.log('Device registered', registration). Also you instead device console using chrome://inspect in google chrome

Comment: Sure let me know

Comment: Cannot find name 'registration'.any , showing this error

Answer (score 0):

In the below code registration variable is valid only inside that subscribe method. whatever you want to do with this variable you have to do that inside the scope

```
pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => {
console.log('Device registered', registration)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.alert(registration.registrationId)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.